# How to use dependency in AngularJS controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

I am making a MEANJS application. I have an AngularJS controller that I would like to use Snoocore in.

https://snoocore.readme.io/

```
'use strict';


angular.module('core').controller('HomeController', ['$scope', 'Authentication', 'snoocore',function($scope, Authentication, Snoocore) {
        // This provides Authentication context.
        $scope.authentication = Authentication;

        var reddit = new Snoocore({
            userAgent: 'test@documentation',
            oauth: {
                type: 'implicit', // required when using implicit OAuth
                mobile: true, // defaults to false.
                key: '', // Only requires the key! No secret needed.
                redirectUri: 'redirectUri set for your app',
                scope: [ 'read', 'flair', 'identity' ] // make sure to set all the scopes you need.
            }
        });
    }
]);
```

I have imported Snoocore via Bower. It is located in

```
public/lib/snoocore
```

The controller is located in

```
public/modules/core/controllers/home.client.controller.js
```

Right now what I am doing is not working. And I am at a bit of a loss. I'm still very new to Angular and the MEANJS system in general.

The console outputs the following

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: snoocoreProvider <- snoocore
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.28/$injector/unpr?p0=snoocoreProvider%20%3C-<section data-ui-view="" class="ng-scope">noocore
    at http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:78:12
    at http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:3801:19
    at Object.getService [as get] (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:3929:39)
    at http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:3806:45
    at getService (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:3929:39)
    at invoke (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:3956:13)
    at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:3976:23)
    at http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:7315:28
    at chrome-extension://ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk/dist/hint.js:1544:22
    at http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:6711:34
```

Comment: are you getting any error on the console ? if yes, what is it ?

Comment: did you include it in your html ```<script src="/path/to/snoocore/dist/Snoocore-browser.js"></script>```? https://snoocore.readme.io/docs/install-include

Comment: @GulfarazYasin i added the console output to the post

Comment: @GulfarazYasin im not sure but try to use the same capital letters (snoocore => Snoocore). 

'$scope', 'Authentication', 'Snoocore',function($scope, Authentication, Snoocore

and add the javascript of snoocore into the scripts
You should take a look at ngAnnotate, this will simplify your code a bit.

Comment: @GulfarazYasin I figured it out. I added a script tag to my HTML head. Is this the way that this is supposed to be done in Angular? Or was the way I was originally trying to do it correct.

Comment: @ryan4888 only after adding the script tag, the library has been included in your application. Downloading it will not include the library to your application. Also, though it does not apply in this case, if the library should be included as a dependency (as in the case of angular plugins) it would fail if you only declare the dependency and not include the library script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the tag

```
<script src="/lib/snoocore/dist/Snoocore-browser.min.js"></script>
```

to my HTML head and changed my controller to look like the following.

```
'use strict';


angular.module('core').controller('HomeController', ['$scope', 'Authentication' ,function($scope, Authentication) {
        // This provides Authentication context.
        $scope.authentication = Authentication;

        var reddit = new Snoocore({
            userAgent: 'test@documentation',
            oauth: {
                type: 'implicit', // required when using implicit OAuth
                mobile: true, // defaults to false.
                key: '', // Only requires the key! No secret needed.
                redirectUri: 'redirectUri set for your app',
                scope: [ 'read', 'flair', 'identity' ] // make sure to set all the scopes you need.
            }
        });

    }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using de oficial library, you can't inject the dependence as a normal AngularJS module because it does not have a AngularJS provider.

I think you should use the library like a normal JS library:

```
 var Snoocore = window.Snoocore;

'use strict';

angular.module('core').controller('HomeController', ['$scope', 'Authentication', function($scope, Authentication) {
        // This provides Authentication context.
        $scope.authentication = Authentication;

        var reddit = new Snoocore({
            userAgent: 'test@documentation',
            oauth: {
                type: 'implicit', // required when using implicit OAuth
                mobile: true, // defaults to false.
                key: '', // Only requires the key! No secret needed.
                redirectUri: 'redirectUri set for your app',
                scope: [ 'read', 'flair', 'identity' ] // make sure to set all the scopes you need.
            }
        });
    }
]);
```

Try this and I hope solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

`Snoocore` is not an angular module so that you cannot have it as an angular dependency. Either create an angular service/factory to wrap the `Snoocore` or use global variable `window.Snoocore`. Also make sure you included the `Snoocore` source file in your HTML.